# 404 Not Found when requesting after deploying to Heroku, works locally (springboot - angular mono)

Tags: java, node.js, angular, express, heroku

Locally my angular frontend + java springboot backend monolithic app works just fine. I am trying to deploy this to Heroku for several days now but its not working. **My endpoints receives 404** while I am sure they work because locally they do. I know my backend is spun because in my heroku logs I can see the Spring logo and everything else. There are no errors. Just 404s for the GET calls to the /endpoints.

I try to be as complete as I can, please ask for more bits of code when necessary.

My project structure is like this

```
.mvn/wrapper
Frontend
src
.gitignore
Procfile
README.md
app.json
mvnw
mvnw.cmd
package-lock.json
package.json
pom.xml
server.js
system.properties
```

I deploy my app with my `Procfile` like this

```
web: java -jar target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar & node server.js
```

My `server.js` looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com'
}));

const distPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Frontend', 'dist', 'frontend');

// Set cache control headers for static files
app.use(express.static(distPath, { setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
  if (filePath.endsWith('.js') || filePath.endsWith('.css')) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
  }
}}));

// Define the middleware function
const setJsonContentType = (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com');
  next(); // Call next to proceed to the next middleware or route handler
};

// Apply the middleware to all API calls
app.use('/', setJsonContentType);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --force --prefix Frontend && npm run build --prefix Frontend"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.15.0",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  }
}
```

Not sure if my `.gitignore` is interesting but I have seen some solutions regarding this, this contains `/dist/` and `node_modules`

My heroku build uses `heroku/java`and `heroku/nodejs` buildpacks as set in the settings of my app at the heroku dashboard. There are no config vars.

My `heroku application log` shows no errors; important lines are
`Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)` and `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`

My extended heroku logs (from the cli) basicly show the Spring boot setup and the 404 for the GET / requests. No extra errors here. Important lines are `Server is running on port 36455` and e.g. of endpoint  `at=info method=GET path="/heroNames" host=dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com request_id=5a07e5b8-a82b-41b3-bbae-cd7122590425 fwd="44.206.218.176" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=489 protocol=https`

It would be so nice if someone could take a look at this and help me, I am stuck for days and I can't find an answer.